# Spring MVC : Handling data in an One to many relationship?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I am implementing a web application using Spring MVC. In my application I need to implement a notification service. Here is the database table for the notification.

```
    CREATE TABLE `notification` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  `message` varchar(100),
  `dateAndTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `notificationType` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userId` bigint(20),
  FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `application_user` (`id`)
);
```

Here userId is the ID of the user of which the notification is sent. This may be either a single user or multiple users. That depends on the value of notificationType. Here is the domain modal I have written for this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "notification")
public class Notification {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String message;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yy-MM-dd-hh-mm")
private Date dateAndTime;

private boolean read;

public static enum NotificationType{
    SINGLE_USER, MULTIPLE_USER
}

//@OneToMany
//@JoinColumn(name="type")
//private User user;

ApplicationUser applicationUser;

private NotificationType notificationType = NotificationType.SINGLE_USER;
......
```

I am not clear how to implement One To Many relationship here. I hope the mysql query is accurate with the above conditions. Please help me with this.

edit:

If NotificationType = SINGLE_USER, I need to send the notification to only one user. If NotificationType = MULTIPLE_USER I need to send notification to several users.

Comment: You need a ManyToMany relationship. Many notifications can refer to many users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table schema you define many to one relationship.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="userId")
private User user;
```

> If NotificationType = SINGLE_USER, I need to send the notification to only one user. If NotificationType = MULTIPLE_USER I need to send notification to several users.

In that case you should create another structure.

For example

```
CREATE USER (
    ...,
    notification_id,
    ...
)

class Notification {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="notification_id")
    private User user;
}
```

Or you could create new table, which will save only notification_id and user_id:

```
CREATE USER_NOTIFICATION (
    user_id,
    notification_id
)
```

And then

```
class Notification {
     @ManyToMany
     @JoinTable(
         name="USER_NOTIFICATION",
         joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
         inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="NOTIFICATION_ID", 
         referencedColumnName="ID"))
  private List<User> users;
}
```

> How do I connect this data with NotificationType?

You have column type in notification table. How you would send notifications - it is your business logic. You don't need do any with table structure for this. If you'd like you could create trigger, which would check your logic on insertion of new (notification_id,user_id) in USER_NOTIFICATION.

Comment: How do I connect this data with NotificationType?